# Get User list from using microsoft graph api

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch all users using Microsoft Graph Api. I have created an application and Added the Application permission like User.Read.All and Directory.Read.All. Now I am trying to get access token from Curl comand like :

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_url=http://localhost:1337/auth/callback' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'`

and it is giving the access token. when I am trying to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users from postman and providing the Authorization headers but it giving the response like :

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
        "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "75c112fd-6019-4cd1-bc4b-928e276",
            "date": "2017-11-29T08:07:35"
        }
    }
}`

Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your application registered? Specifically, since you're using a V2 AAD auth flow (providing scopes vs. resources), I think you'll need to have it registered in the Application Registration Portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com).

Comment: I created it in apps.dev.microsoft.com.

Comment: @user9873999 have you been able to solve this? I am stuck at the same point.

Comment: you have to make the first call for the admin consent and once Admin approves the permission then you can access all the information.

Comment: @user9873999 do you know if there's any way for the admin to approve it beforehand (i.e. on apps.dev.microsoft.com)? I don't want to build out a web app just so I can click a button to authorize my app, I'd rather use text only/command line...